# How to prevent "runaway" writer processes during fsfreeze/sync/snapshots in linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems, fsfreeze

**tl;dr** How can processes writing data to disk be temporarily stopped, so as to prevent them to screwup fsfreeze/sync?

**long story**

My question is about a process that is writing data to be persisted on disk (storage device) in a "*runaway*" fashion.

this for instance is a process that I consider "*runaway*"

```
yes "$(base64 /dev/urandom | head -n 20)" > /mnt/fs1/file
```

since in all likeliness would be able to generate data faster than  it can be writen to disk. (this could even be worse see below)

Doing a `sync`/`fsfreeze`/(`btrfs subvolume snapshot`) such a "*runaway*"-process would appear to become an obstacle or at the least a considerable delay. Indeed I have experimented the `fsfreeze` on a `btrfs` and it "bit its own tail" as it hang itself.

As an *answer* I seek advice how to prevent any such processes to be running while I persist the current buffered fs data to disk.

A process that is such a "*runaway-writer*" would appear unlikely at first, as it would anyway fill up the available storage space (free space available in the filesystem).
This seems to be however not the case as a writer could continously overwrite the same file content in such a fashion

```
RANDSTRING="$(base64 /dev/urandom | head -n 20 | tr -d '\n')"
while true
do
  yes "$RANDSTRING" | head -c 100M > /mnt/fs1/file
done
```

Above bash script could also be rewriten in a small C program so as to avoid multiple open system calls, and just seek to the start of the /mnt/fs1/file. Bottom line being that there is constantly new data at a higher rate as can be writen out to the storage device, which should make sync and fsfreeze to never actually successfully finish.

Comment: Couldn't you just `kill -STOP` them?

Comment: @UncleBilly I am not sure. I guess this would require to know the *runaway* processes and fail for the more generic case, right? Or do you imply a way to `kill -STOP [all processes]` (not sure if this i actually possible?